# fbAsyncInit: username displayed after 3 times refresh

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the PHP Facebook API and the Javascript part to check if an user is logged in.

But my username will be displayed after 3 times refreshing the page. Here are the steps that I take.

1. Log into Facebook
2. Go to my website (first time visit)
3. Refresh my website 2 times
4. My username will be displayed

Does someone know something about this problem?

Comment: 1) what do you mean by "*log into Facebook*"? do you mean using Facebook connect while the user is on your website? 2) show us your "Facebook Connect" code. 3) check the sessions during the visits. 4) what browser are you using?

Comment: ifaour, I already fixed it. I included the Facebook Javascript SDK code 2 times. One in the header and one in the bottom. When I removed the one in the reader, the problem was solved. Thanks for your help.